# Создание бота с api на node.js

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, express, архитектура, бот

Создаю бота для **discord** на **node.js** при помощи **discord.js**. Также у него будет **api** на **express**.
Api будет тесно взаимодействовать с ботом.

- Есть ли похожие проекты с открытым кодом, на которые можно ориентироваться?
- Как правильно разделить две части проекта?
- Какую структуру проекта будет лучше использовать?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.